# How to get Current Product Seller Id in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get Current Product Seller Id in magento.If I can get the Id I can show up their address country. Is there Anyone can help me with this?

I get the seller name by attribute

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('creator_id');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Product ID you can get its seller name, below is code sample for it ( magento 1.9)

```
  $ProductID = 1000; ///$_product->getProductId(); you can get it like this
  $allSellers= Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=> $ProductID ));
  $sellerID = 0;
    foreach ($allSellers as $seller) {
        $sellerID= $seller->getUserid();  // here you have seller ID
        $sellerName = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sellerID)->getName(); // here you have seller name
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This codes can be used if you are using Marketplace Extension.

Assuming the product ID is 10.

```
$prodID = 10;

$collection_prod = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid', array('eq'=>$prodID));

$sellerID = '';
foreach($collection_prod as $collection){
    $sellerID = $collection->getUserid(); //get the seller ID
}

$sellerAddress_Collection = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq'=>$sellerID));

foreach($sellerAddress_Collection as $sellerAddress_Collections){
   $addressID = $sellerAddress_Collections->getEntityId(); //get the address ID of the seller

   $seller_collection_address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressID); // load the address ID of the seller

   $zipcode = $seller_collection_address->getPostcode(); //zipcode
   $country_id = $seller_collection_address->getCountryId(); //country id
   $city = $seller_collection_address->getCity(); // City
   $street1 = $seller_collection_address->getStreet(1);  //street 1
   $street2 = $seller_collection_address->getStreet(2);  //street 2
   $tel = $seller_collection_address->getTelephone(); //Telephone
}
```